# Missing CSRF Token on csrf protection rule - Sticky SessionID Data Changed - IP Address Mismatch on session hijacking rule

Tags: php, csrf

We are running a site developed in PHP for e-payment. Consumers will sign in to our site, know the bill then click on the payment button. Then user will be routed to BillDesk (epayment gateway). The URL will contain bill amount, name of the consumer along with the return URL (Return url: http://mydomain.com/paymentResponse.php, mydomain is our website). After the payment made by the consumer, BillDesk website will return the transaction ID along with consumer name to the Return URL, that we have provided. It was working perfectly, but last month our data center changed their security measures. Now, after the payment made, control is not returned to our domain from BillDesk. The error message is:

```
 Missing CSRF Token on csrf protection rule , Sticky SessionID Data Changed - IP Address
 Mismatch on session hijacking rule, Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert on sql 
injection attacks rule (Pattern match "([\\\\~\\\\!\\\\@\\\\#\\\\$\\\\%\\\\^\\\\&\\\\*\\\\
(\\\\)\\\\-\\\\+\\\\=\\\\{\\\\}\\\\\\\\]\\\\|\\\\:\\\\;\\"\\\\'\\\\\\xc2\\xb4\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x99\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x98\\\\`\\\\
<\\\\>].*){4,}"), Sticky SessionID Data Changed - IP Address Mismatch warning on session 
hijacking rule were encountered during accessing the website
```

Is it because the return URL we are providing does not contain session id or any thing else ?